# Why input is broken when value is the same?

Tags: vuejs2

I want to have a controlled input, and set keep its value unchanged on any input. The problem is: it works only when I type in for the first time (i.e. it's set to 1). But then it stops working and you can type in any value. Why?

```
<input :value="message" @input="message = 1" />
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-fire-in9yn?file=/index.html:162-209

Comment: Have you considered simply setting the `readonly` attribute?

Comment: @StephenThomas I would like to know the reason why it doesn't work in my case as well

Comment: Could explain the use case for this input?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is prevent the user from changing the `<input>` value, you can do that with simple HTML. You don't need Vue at all.

```
<input value="1" readonly>
```

Comment: I would like to know the reason why it doesn't work in my case as well

Comment: Because Vue will only update the `<input>` element when it detects that the value of `message` has changed. The first time the user enters a key, the value changes from `""` to `1` and Vue detects that as a change. The next time the user enters a key, the value of `message` "changes" from `1` to `1`, which, of course, isn't a change. Since Vue hasn't detected a change, it doesn't update the `<input>` element. So the element keeps whatever value the user has entered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend doing this, but this would achieve your expected behavior:

```
<input v-model="message" @input="message = 1" />
```

This works because it is a "2-way binding" using [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#v-model-with-Components), which means changes to the input's value are propagated automatically, so a state change is triggered, because the new value of input is propagated (in the state) and then `message = 1` get triggered afterwards and triggers a state change which updates the input element.

The original using `:value=message` is one-way, so changes in value to the input box are not automatically propagated to your component's state, and so Vue just sees a component with the same value bound to the message prop and does not update.